# How should I import/run a .pkb file for Oracle Database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to import/run a .pkb file for an Oracle Database. But I am not sure how should I do it. This pkb file updates a stored procedure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `.pkb` seems to be `PACKAGE BODY`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: it contains an update to a stored procedure. My understanding is that it would update that stored procedure when I run it. how should I make it happen?

Answer (score 5):

Open the .pkb file in PL/SQL Developer, Oracle SQL Developer, or whatever software you use to connect to the database.  Execute the contents of the file and it will update your package body and its procedures.  Or in SQL*Plus you can run it with @path/file.pkb.

Answer (score 3):

To run this in SQL Developer, open the file in a worksheet (alt+F10) under the appropriate database connection. Rather than running the script with F9 or ctrl+Enter, compile the file with [Compile Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yez6u.png) in the worksheet menu.

You should receive the message 'Compiled' or 'Compiled - with errors' depending on if it successfully compiled